# Creating generic imagebuttons with different onclick listeners

Tags: android, imagebutton, generic-programming

I'm trying to create a generic page that creates image buttons with URL attached to them so they redirect you to a webpage on click. The number of the buttons is also generated on compile, as well as the links, they are retrieved from an online source.

My problem is, when I try to create an OnClickListener in a generic loop, they are not created until the button is clicked, therefore not until the end of the loop.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
  ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
  int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids[position]);
  String imageFile = MainActivity.GetbyId(id, MainActivity.getSaleArray()).imageURL;
  String link=MainActivity.GetbyId(id, MainActivity.getSaleArray()).link;
  imageButton.setTag(link);

  imageButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse((String) imageButton.getTag()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
     });
```

In the code above, I have an array of unknown size with ids and links, I have the data I require in each button's Tag but I cannot call them with imageButton.getTag() in OnClick block, it requires the variables to be 'final'. Can you help me find a way around this?

The rest of the code works perfectly, except the line intent.setData(...)

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't set `imageButton` to final?

Comment: how many image buttons altogether? should each button direct you to different links?

Comment: I cannot tell how many buttons, it depends on the size of the array I get generically. And yes, each link goes to a seperate button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `link` to be final and directly use it inside the `OnClickListener`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids[position]);
String imageFile = MainActivity.GetbyId(id, MainActivity.getSaleArray()).imageURL;
final String link = MainActivity.GetbyId(id, MainActivity.getSaleArray()).link;

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Link is a variable too, it is a different link for every button, that's my problem. As far as I know, that would make the link unchangeable once assigned, no?

Comment: This seems to work for some reason, although I do not understand what 'final' really does in this example. Alas, it worked. Cheers buddy.

Comment: I assume this piece of code is inside a loop? If so, `link` is declared in each loop, thus the `final` only means that you are not able to modify `link` inside that loop.